# I want to used lang to mark languages.In the process of authentication,This parameter is lost

Tags: java, redirect, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

`http://localhost:8080/auth/login?lang=en` I want to used `lang` to mark languages.In the process of authentication,This parameter is lost.
I read the source code.
`LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint.commence`
```java
public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {

```
    String redirectUrl = null;

    if (useForward) {

        if (forceHttps && "http".equals(request.getScheme())) {
            // First redirect the current request to HTTPS.
            // When that request is received, the forward to the login page will be
            // used.
            redirectUrl = buildHttpsRedirectUrlForRequest(request);
        }

        if (redirectUrl == null) {
            String loginForm = determineUrlToUseForThisRequest(request, response,
                    authException);

            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("Server side forward to: " + loginForm);
            }

            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(loginForm);

            dispatcher.forward(request, response);

            return;
        }
    }
    else {
        // redirect to login page. Use https if forceHttps true

        redirectUrl = buildRedirectUrlToLoginPage(request, response, authException);

    }

    redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, redirectUrl);
}
```

```

Rewrite `redirectUrl` 
`AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer`

`java
private void addAuthenticationEntryPoint(HttpSecurity http, OAuth2SsoProperties sso)
            throws Exception {
        ...
        exceptions.defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint(sso.getLoginPath()),
                preferredMatcher);
        ...
    }`

That need to Overwrite too much code.
I wonder if I didn't find a suitable existing configuration to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by Filter
save the msg in session